# Jboss server error while adding JMS queue service

Tags: java, spring, jms, message-queue, jboss5.x

I am new to JBoss JMS queue service.

Currently, I am working in a production code using JBosss Messaging Server, where several queues have been configured in a separate **example-service.xml** file

All queues are working fine and each queue has it own separate MDB listeners which will consumes all the messages from Queue.

However, I am getting following issues:

- I am not able to browse any of the Queue values using QueueBrowser, even if the queue has some values before it is being consumed by the MDB listeners.

However, **I have stopped the MDB listeners**, now all the messages I am sending to queue is still available in queue and I am able to browse all the queue values

I don't know why I am not able to browse the Queue values while MDB listeners are enabled? I have also attached My configuration files here:

My current Queue configuration files are as follows:

**example-service.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server>
  <mbean code="org.jboss.jms.server.destination.QueueService"
   name="jboss.messaging.destination:service=Queue,name=sampleQueue_1" xmbean-dd="xmdesc/Queue-xmbean.xml">
    <depends optional-attribute-name="ServerPeer">jboss.messaging:service=ServerPeer</depends>
    <depends>jboss.messaging:service=PostOffice</depends>
    <attribute name="MaxDeliveryAttempts">4</attribute>
    <attribute name="RedeliveryDelay">10000</attribute>
  </mbean>
  <mbean code="org.jboss.jms.server.destination.QueueService"
   name="jboss.messaging.destination:service=Queue,name=sampleQueue_2" xmbean-dd="xmdesc/Queue-xmbean.xml">
    <depends optional-attribute-name="ServerPeer">jboss.messaging:service=ServerPeer</depends>
    <depends>jboss.messaging:service=PostOffice</depends>
    <attribute name="MaxDeliveryAttempts">4</attribute>
    <attribute name="RedeliveryDelay">10000</attribute>
  </mbean>
  <mbean code="org.jboss.jms.server.destination.QueueService"
   name="jboss.messaging.destination:service=Queue,name=sampleQueue_3" xmbean-dd="xmdesc/Queue-xmbean.xml">
    <depends optional-attribute-name="ServerPeer">jboss.messaging:service=ServerPeer</depends>
    <depends>jboss.messaging:service=PostOffice</depends>
    <attribute name="MaxDeliveryAttempts">4</attribute>
    <attribute name="RedeliveryDelay">10000</attribute>
  </mbean>
  <mbean code="org.jboss.jms.server.destination.QueueService"
   name="jboss.messaging.destination:service=Queue,name=sampleQueue_4" xmbean-dd="xmdesc/Queue-xmbean.xml">
    <depends optional-attribute-name="ServerPeer">jboss.messaging:service=ServerPeer</depends>
    <depends>jboss.messaging:service=PostOffice</depends>
    <attribute name="MaxDeliveryAttempts">1</attribute>
  </mbean>
</server>
```

**jboss.xml**

```
<jboss>

   <enterprise-beans>
      <message-driven>
         <ejb-name>update/sample1MDB</ejb-name>
         <destination-jndi-name>queue/sampleQueue_1</destination-jndi-name>
         <configuration-name>Singleton Message Driven Bean</configuration-name>
      </message-driven>
      <message-driven>
         <ejb-name>update/sample2MDB</ejb-name>
         <destination-jndi-name>queue/sampleQueue_2</destination-jndi-name>
         <configuration-name>Singleton Message Driven Bean</configuration-name>
      </message-driven>
      <message-driven>
         <ejb-name>update/sample3MDB</ejb-name>
         <destination-jndi-name>queue/sampleQueue_3</destination-jndi-name>
         <configuration-name>Singleton Message Driven Bean</configuration-name>
      </message-driven>
      <message-driven>
         <ejb-name>update/sample4MDB</ejb-name>
         <destination-jndi-name>queue/sampleQueue_4</destination-jndi-name>
         <configuration-name>Singleton Message Driven Bean</configuration-name>
      </message-driven>
    </enterprise-beans>

   <resource-managers>
   </resource-managers>

  <!--
    | for container settings, you can merge in jboss-container.xml
    | this can contain <invoker-proxy-bindings/> and <container-configurations/>
  -->

</jboss>
```

**standardjboss.xml**

```
<container-configuration>
      <container-name>Singleton Message Driven Bean</container-name>
      <call-logging>false</call-logging>
      <invoker-proxy-binding-name>singleton-message-driven-bean</invoker-proxy-binding-name>
      <container-interceptors>
        <interceptor>org.jboss.ejb.plugins.ProxyFactoryFinderInterceptor</interceptor>
        <!-- CMT -->
        <interceptor transaction="Container">org.jboss.ejb.plugins.TxInterceptorCMT</interceptor>
        <interceptor transaction="Container">org.jboss.ejb.plugins.CallValidationInterceptor</interceptor>
        <interceptor transaction="Container">org.jboss.ejb.plugins.MessageDrivenInstanceInterceptor</interceptor>
        <!-- BMT -->
        <interceptor transaction="Bean">org.jboss.ejb.plugins.MessageDrivenInstanceInterceptor</interceptor>
        <interceptor transaction="Bean">org.jboss.ejb.plugins.MessageDrivenTxInterceptorBMT</interceptor>
        <interceptor transaction="Bean">org.jboss.ejb.plugins.CallValidationInterceptor</interceptor>
        <interceptor>org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionInterceptor</interceptor>
      </container-interceptors>
      <instance-pool>org.jboss.ejb.plugins.MessageDrivenInstancePool</instance-pool>
      <instance-cache></instance-cache>
      <persistence-manager></persistence-manager>
      <container-pool-conf>
        <MaximumSize>1</MaximumSize>
        <strictMaximumSize/>        
      </container-pool-conf>
    </container-configuration>
```

**weblogic-ejb-jar.xml**

```
<weblogic-enterprise-bean>
      <ejb-name>update/sampleMDB</ejb-name>
      <message-driven-descriptor>
         <pool>
            <max-beans-in-free-pool>1</max-beans-in-free-pool>
            <initial-beans-in-free-pool>1</initial-beans-in-free-pool>
         </pool>
         <destination-jndi-name>queue/sampleQueue_1</destination-jndi-name>
      </message-driven-descriptor>
      <transaction-descriptor>
         <trans-timeout-seconds>36000</trans-timeout-seconds>
      </transaction-descriptor>
      <reference-descriptor>
      </reference-descriptor>

   </weblogic-enterprise-bean>
```

And, Iam using the following code to browse the values from the Queue

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        QueueConnectionFactory queueConnectionFactory;
        QueueConnection queueConnection = null;
        try {
            queueConnectionFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory)BrowseQueue.getInitialContext().lookup("ConnectionFactory");
            queueConnection = queueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection();
            queueConnection.start();
            String queueName = "sampleQueue_1";
            Queue queueToExamine = (Queue)BrowseQueue.getInitialContext().lookup("queue/"+queueName);
            QueueSession queueSession = queueConnection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            QueueBrowser queueBrowser = queueSession.createBrowser(queueToExamine);
            Enumeration<?> enumeration = queueBrowser.getEnumeration();
            while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
                Object object = (Object) enumeration.nextElement();
                if(object instanceof ObjectMessage) {
                    ObjectMessage objectMessage = (ObjectMessage)object;
                    System.out.println(objectMessage);
                }
            }
            queueConnection.close();
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Context getInitialContext() throws NamingException {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.iiop.naming.ORBInitialContextFactory");
        properties.setProperty(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
        properties.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "localhost:4557");
        return new InitialContext(properties);
    }
```

Is there any configuration I am missing? or anything wrong I am doing?

Please help me, on why I am not able to browse the queue values before its being consumed?

Thanks in advance..