# Unable to browse JMS Queue values with MDB enabled

Tags: java, spring, jms, message-queue, jboss5.x

I am working in Jboss Messaging Queue server.

I have configured several queue in a separate **sample-service.xml** and I have configured each queue a Message Driven Bean class.

Now, I am able to enqueue values in the queue and also able to consume the enqueued values from the Queue.

My Problem is, I am not able to browse any of the Queue values even though the Queue has some queue values before its being consumed by its MDB.  The QueueBrowser always shows empty values.

**Note:**

If I disabled the Message Driven Bean, I am able to browse the Queue values.

Please click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28473761/jboss-server-error-while-adding-jms-queue-service) to view more information regarding My Queue Configurations.

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Why would you expect to be able to browse messages on the queue if you have an MDB consuming the messages?

Comment: @mikea, I would like to check whether the the item I am enqueuing exists in the queue or not. If it exists, I will avoid such values from being enqueued in the Queue.

Comment: @mikea I am having a Singleton MDB consuming the messages one by one. I am able to see the pending messages in the queue through jboss admin console. However I am not able to browse the queue using QueueBrowser. My question is, Can we able to browse the queue when a singleton MDB is consuming it?